# need help in registering AxInterop.MSMAPI dll in windows 7 32 bit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6

I have move a old vb6 windows application to new system with vs 2010 and windows 7. This application is using **AxInterop.MSMAPI** and **AxInterop.ComctlLib** dll in it. When i try to compile, i am getting the following warning

```
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
```

So I am trying to register them by using RegSvr32

```
run --> regsvr32 D:\somepath\AxInterop.MSMAPI.dll
```

but i am getting the following error

```
The Module "D:\somepath\AxInterop.MSMAPI.dll" as loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "D:\somepath\AxInterop.MSMAPI.dll" is a valid DLL OR OCX file and then try again.
```

Need some help in registering these two dlls

thanks in advance

Comment: You will be better off if you create a COM based .Net DLL that uses the MailClient and exposes the methods you need. Then you can reference that instead. [Calling .Net from VB6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248) I believe some of the APIs required by the old MAPI has gone away as of VISTA.

Comment: thanks Steve.. but for me that a huge and non billable work to do... Any other way to crack this out.

Comment: The old MAPI does not work so you have to use something else. If you spend some time searching the web, you might find someone who has done this before and get thier code from them. Try CodeProject, here is the first result I found there: [MAPI.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2048/Simple-MAPI-NET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a 64 bit Windows? If so you have to make sure that you are running the regsvr32 command from the syswow64 folder, like this:

```
c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 D:\somepath\AxInterop.MSMAPI.dll
```

Comment: am using 32 bit windows

Comment: Hello every one i got it worked. I had generated a setup (exe) from  old system and installed in new system and then... it worked. Dlls auto registered and the windows application is working fine.